# Improvement of chess engines over time

Tags: engines, history, statistics, computer-chess

Chess engine strength has increased considerably over time due to increase of computer strength, but also improvement in algorithms/parameters.

Is there any statistics or graph out there which shows this improvement? Perhaps something like computer Elo vs time and compared to computer strength!?

Comment: http://talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=59470&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=graph+stockfish&topic_view=flat&start=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a post about Stockfish improvement over the years.

[image]

http://talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=62822